A better / correct way to compare and aggregate Vectors containing orders in C++?
I have not written any meaningful C++ in a very long time and mostly been using Python / Java for the past several years - so I am wondering/hoping if there is a better way of coding for the following in C++:
I have an order book which contains (financial) market orders.
The order book is represented in a Vector where each vector entry contains a order entry i.e. order price + order size (and side Bid/Ask)
It is quite possible that there can be multiple order entries at the same price e.g.
A : 99 : 5000     
A : 99 : 2342     
A : 98 : 6640    
A : 98 : 1800      
A : 97.78 : 2731       
A : 97 : 14704       
A : 97 : 5281      
A : 97 : 75641      
A : 96 : 3200   

Where A = Ask, Column 2 (99-96) is the Order Price and Column 3 is the size of the order.
I need to end up with something like:
A : 99 : 7342    
A : 98 : 8440    
A : 97.78 : 2731     
A : 97 : 95626     
A : 96 : 3200

I am currently using code that looks something like:
for (auto i = 0u; i + 1 < mboAggreg.size();) {
    if (mboAggreg[i].OrderPrc == mboAggreg[i + 1].OrderPrc)
    {
        mboAggreg[i].OrderSize += mboAggreg[i + 1].OrderSize;
    mboAggreg.erase(mboAggreg.begin() + i + 1);
    // dont increment index - as we may have more than two orders with the same price
    }
    else
    i++;
}   

That works, but I am wondering if there is a better/cleaner/correct C++ (STL) way of doing the above?
I will be expecting to do the above for several thousand order books - some of which are quite volatile/highly traded - so any effeciency would be most useful.
Thanks in advance..

Erase in a large vector is a terrible idea, you're moving all the subsequent elements in the array, so at the end will have O(n^2) complexity. It would seem much more sensible to just create a new vector (and perhaps swap them once done aggregating).

The code works. The correct site for the question is https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Using two source and target sliding indexes you can call erase() once.

Did you sort the order book only for doing this operation or is the data naturally sorted so that same OrderPrc entries are next to each other? If you had to sort, then don't do that and use an unordered_map instead. In Python you would write c = {}; for OrderPrc, OrderSize in OrderBook: c[OrderPrc] = c.get(OrderPrc, 0) + OrderSize to run in linear time rather than O(n log n) for sorting or O(n^2) for erasing. You can do the same with an unordered_map in C++

and if it is naturally sorted, then create a new vector with unique entries. About the same big-O complexity but faster in practice

Thanks for the replies.
Each vector will probably have an around 10-150 elements and the raw data is not sorted, I sort it to do the above aggregation.
There will, however, be 1000s of these vectors and as I am dealing with real-time streaming data, the order books can update quite frequently.
However, I will only need to do the sorting and aggregation a few times of the day.
I will explore the unorded_map and new vector options. Thanks

If you need an aggregate, instead of looping over erasing, it might be a lot better to create a new collection to hold the aggragate data.
If the order vector is unordered, then its probably best to create a map collection, lookup existing price and either add to it or create as you go.
If they are guaranteed to be ordered, and reusing the vector is important for memory allocation issues, tthen you can still do it within the vector - use 2 iterators, one steps through calculating the values as you have, the other can be an insertion one that overwrites the beginning entries with the accumulated totals. Once complete you can erase the remainder of the vector using the 2nd iterator as a startpoint.

Erasing elements in the middle of a vector takes O(n) time. Since you do it in a loop over all entries, the algorithm will perform in O(n^2) time. Not great. You can use a variation of the erase-remove idiom instead.
#include <algorithm>
// using std::find_if
#include <numeric>
// using std::accumulate
#include <vector>


enum class Type { Ask };
struct Order {
    Type type;
    int OrderPrc;
    int OrderSize;
};

void aggregateOrders(std::vector<Order>& mboAggreg)
{
    using iterator = std::vector<Order>::iterator;
    iterator in, out;
    iterator end = mboAggreg.end();
    for(in = out = mboAggreg.begin(); in != end; ++out) {
        // find adjacent entries with same Order price
        iterator end_of_same = std::find_if(in + 1, end,
              [OrderPrc=in->OrderPrc](const Order& order) {
                  return order.OrderPrc != OrderPrc;
        });
        // copy to current output location
        *out = *in;
        // sum up all order sizes
        out->OrderSize = std::accumulate(in, end_of_same, 0,
              [](int left, const Order& right) {
                  return left + right.OrderSize;
        });
        in = end_of_same;
    }
    // Remove trailing, removed entries
    mboAggreg.erase(out, end);
}

As discussed in comments, if the order book is not already sorted, it is faster to skip sorting and instead use an unordered_map for N constant time lookups.
#include <algorithm>
// using std::transform
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

void aggregateOrders(std::vector<Order>& mboAggreg)
{
    using map_type = std::unordered_map<int, Order>;
    map_type uniqueOrders;
    // accumulate duplicates based on OrderPrc
    for(const Order& order: mboAggreg) {
        auto inserted = uniqueOrders.try_emplace(order.OrderPrc, order);
        if(! inserted.second) // duplicate OrderPrc
            inserted.first->second.OrderSize += order.OrderSize;
    }
    // copy unique entries back to the vector. Ordering will differ
    std::vector<Order>::iterator new_end = std::transform(
          uniqueOrders.begin(), uniqueOrders.end(), mboAggreg.begin(),
          [](map_type::const_reference keyValue) { return keyValue.second; }); 
    // remove trailing entries
    mboAggreg.erase(new_end, mboAggreg.end());
}

Both approaches rely on Order objects to be cheap to copy. Modifications to avoid copies and use more moves are possible.
We can actually combine the two approaches to avoid the copying and make the whole thing more efficient but you have to be cautious when you extend the code; don't resize the vector or it might invalidate the iterators. As a bonus it keeps the original order of the unique entries.
void aggregateOrders(std::vector<Order>& mboAggreg)
{
    using iterator = std::vector<Order>::iterator;
    using map_type = std::unordered_map<int, iterator>;
    map_type uniqueOrders;
    iterator in, out, end;
    /*
     * Accumulate duplicates based on OrderPrc. 
     * We store the unique entries in the front of mboAggreg and keep track of
     * their location via the map
     */
    for(in = out = mboAggreg.begin(), end = mboAggreg.end(); in != end; ++in) {
        auto inserted = uniqueOrders.try_emplace(in->OrderPrc, out);
        if(inserted.second) { // new OrderPrc
            if(in != out) // copy order to output position
                *out = std::move(*in);
            ++out;
        }
        else // duplicate. Add OrderSize
            inserted.first->second->OrderSize += in->OrderSize;
    }
    mboAggreg.erase(out, end); // remove trailing entries
}

Since you are coming from a Python background, here is a rough equivalent in that language:
# approach 1
import itertools

def aggregateOrders(mboAggreg):
    replacement = []
    for _, samePrc in itertools.groupby(
          mboAggreg, key=lambda order: order.OrderPrc):
        order = next(samePrc)
        order.OrderSize += sum(dup.OrderSize for dup in samePrc)
        replacement.append(order)
    mboAggreg[:] = replacement


# approach 2
def aggregateOrders(mboAggreg):
    uniqueOrders = {}
    for order in mboAggreg:
        if order.OrderPrc in uniqueOrders:
            uniqueOrders[order.OrderPrc].OrderSize += order.OrderSize
        else:
            uniqueOrders[order.OrderPrc] = order
    mboAggreg[:] = list(uniqueOrders.values())


# approach 3
def aggregateOrders(mboAggreg):
    uniqueOrders = {}
    for order in mboAggreg:
        if order.OrderPrc in uniqueOrders:
            uniqueindex = uniqueOrders[order.OrderPrc]
            mboAggreg[uniqueindex].OrderSize += order.OrderSize
        else:
            uniqueindex = len(uniqueOrders)
            mboAggreg[uniqueindex] = order
            uniqueOrders[order.OrderPrc] = uniqueindex
    del mboAggreg[len(uniqueOrders):]


Thanks - the unordered_map is looking like the best option given that the raw data is not sorted.!
Sorry, I cant upvote your answer as I don't have the necessary rep points..

@NULseg I added a third version that should be faster but also a bit more complex. Note that if your order book is only a few 100 entries, big O estimations may not apply and benchmarking may be required

Hi @Homer512
Thanks for the revised code - much appreciated.
Using your combined code is approx 25% faster than my original code - which will make a considerable difference when dealing large highly volatile order books in real-time.
At first, it looked like your code was not working as some of my price points were missing from the end result.
I then realised I had overlooked the warning about int / double - my OrderPrc is a double.
All good now - Thanks!

@NULseg In case this is a serious application dealing with financial data, please read Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?

Thanks for the information.
At the transport layer, the raw price data is transmitted as integers with a mantissa to indicate where the decimal is.
It is then being converted by the real-time API to a double - for the purpose of sorting etc. No further calculations will be performed on the Price field once converted from the raw data. The calculations are only done on the Order size which is an Integer field.
